# Nested table using pageblock

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable, table, pageblocksection, nested

So I want to add a nested  table for another table. I'm able to add **table 2** as nested for **table 1.** I could do this by adding a pageblocktable table 2 inside the last column of the pageblocktable of table 1(the parent table). Following is my code...

```
<apex:pageblocksection title="Order Lines" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="1">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!gp.ct}" var="p">   //page block 1
        <apex:column></apex:column>
        <apex:column width="40%" >
            <apex:pageblocksection title="Shipment Information" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!gp.ot}" var="q"> //page block 2 inside page block 1 in column
                <apex:column > 
                </apex:column>                 
                </apex:pageBlockTable>  
            </apex:pageblocksection>
        </apex:column> 
    </apex:pageBlockTable>  
</apex:pageblockSection>
```

Here is the output:

[image]

So my question is, can I add the child pageblocktable (table 2) so that it spans across the entire length of each row in the parent table beneath the other columns?

Any suggestion would be helpful.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use `breakBefore` and  `colspan` parameters of the `apex:column`:

```
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageblocksection title="Order Lines" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="1">

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accounts}" var="a">
        <apex:column value="{!a.Name}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!a.Street__c}"/>

        <apex:column breakBefore="true" colspan="2">
            <apex:pageblocksection title="Shipment Information" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="1">
                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!a.contacts}" var="c">
                    <apex:column value="{!c.Id}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!c.Name}"/>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>

</apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you don't want the second green header bar to appear, I think if you simply remove the second nested pageBlockSection, you'll get what you want.

```
<apex:pageblocksection title="Order Lines" showheader="true" collapsible="true" columns="1">
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!gp.ct}" var="p">   //page block 1
    <apex:column></apex:column>
    <apex:column width="40%" >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!gp.ot}" var="q"> //page block 2 inside page block 1 in column
            <apex:column > 
            </apex:column>                 
            </apex:pageBlockTable>  
    </apex:column> 
 </apex:pageBlockTable>  
</apex:pageblockSection>
```

Comment: No I need the green header. I just want the child table should come right below the parent table. Is it possible?

Comment: ok. now I understand.

Comment: Hi peter. You can see my code. I don't want to add a new pageblocktable in another column of another pageblocktable. @mast0r has already posted what I desired. A child table below a parent table. Thanks for helping. :)