# Can I show master - detail within a lightning table component

Tags: lightning, master-detail, nested, datatables.js

I want to show parent & child rows in table such that  that on clicking a + on master row i show the child rows with different data structure right below the master row?

something like pageblock nested tables : [Nested table using pageblock](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49545/nested-table-using-pageblock)

Comment: yes you should be able to do that by multiple aura:iteration in the component.